# Getting SQLCODE=-104 on binding a parameter for DB2 query in Python

Tags: python-3.x, db2

Assuming the data.xlsx looks like this:

Column_Name | Table_Name

CUST_ID_1   | Table_1

CUST_ID_2   | Table_2

Here are the SQLs that I'm trying to generate by using the *bind_param* for db2 in Python:

SELECT *CUST_ID_1* FROM *TABLE_1* WHERE *CUST_ID_1* = 12345

SELECT *CUST_ID_2* FROM *TABLE_2* WHERE *CUST_ID_2* = 12345

And this is how Im trying to generate this query:

```
import ibm_db
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

validate_sql = "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ?=12345"
validate_stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, validate_sql)

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')

for i in df.index:
    ibm_db.bind_param(validate_stmt, 1, df['Column_Name'][i])
    ibm_db.bind_param(validate_stmt, 2, df['Table_Name'][i])
    ibm_db.bind_param(validate_stmt, 3, df['Column_Name'][i])
    ibm_db.execute(validate_stmt)
    validation_result = ibm_db.fetch_both(validate_stmt)

    while validation_result != False:
        print(validation_result[0])
        validation_result = ibm_db.fetch_both(validate_stmt)
```

When I try to execute this code, Im hitting a SQLCODE=-104 error.

Any idea how the syntax should be for parameter binding?

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 major errors.
1. You can’t use a parameter marker for a table or column name (2-nd & 3-rd parameters).
2. You must specify the data type of the parameter marker, if it’s not possible to understand it from the query (1-st parameter). You must use something like «cast(? as *data-type-desired*)». But it’s just for you info, since you try to use it here as a column name, which is not possible as described in 1).

Comment: Thank you @Mark. Is there any other way I can parameterize the column name and table name? I have about 200 tables that I need to perform the 'select *' on. I was hoping if I can have the column name & table name in a excel sheet..then I can just call them in a 'for' loop to execute the 'select *'

Comment: Construct a `select` statement dynamically and use the `execute_immediate` function instead.